# Transparency through multiple views

Tags: ios, swift, calayer, mask

I have an icon image that is ontop of a UIView with a black color. I would like to be able to see the bottom view within the outline of the icon image.

Guessing CALayer is the way to go, just not too sure how to use it

Useful information

```
-Splash Screen Background = gray
-Splash Screen Size = view.frame.size
-Icon image size = 75 x 75
```

Thanks

Comment: Icon image with a transparent background?

Comment: Add transparent icon in the transparent portion of view . Create transparency only in particular portion of view using `DrawRect` method.

Comment: use a transparent png image, it will work

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the UIImageView for icon then set its alpha less than 1 i.e. 0.8 or 0.5 as you want the transparency.
Otherwise user the transparent image.